# SQLite, история взаимодействий

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Есть-ли и в sqlite базовые инструменты для мониторинга взаимодействий с базой данных?

Мне нужно что бы пользователь, которого я создам, мог только просматривать данные. Можно-ли в sqlite создать разграничение прав с помощью пользователей?

Comment: Нет, это механизмы для полноценных СУБД, а не для встраиваемого движка, имеющего в названии слово "Lite".

Comment: Просто используя navicat увидел раздел пользователи для данной субд, и кроме их создания большего функционала связанного с этим разделом нет.
В следствии чего возник этот вопрос. То есть можно  считать этот раздел мертвым?(что автор неосознанно добавил этот раздел для данной субд)

Comment: у sqlite'а есть [расширение](https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/ext/userauth/user-auth.txt), которое даёт поддержку авторизации пользователей по паролю... но ИМХО на практике от него пользы как с козла молока...